# What are conditions on $x$ that make roots of $y^2 + 2xy - 2 = 0$ greater than 1 in absolute value?

Tags: inequality

Original question: How do we solve $\sqrt{x^2+2}<x-1$? If $x>1$, the solution is $x<-0.5$ which does not make sense. What if $x<1$?

Update: Thank you for all answers. Actually, the original question was: "What are conditions on $x$ that make the roots of the following equation in absolute value strictly greater than one?"
$$y^2 + 2xy - 2 = 0$$
The discriminant is $D = 4x^2 +8$ and so solutions are $y_1 = -x-\sqrt{x^2+2}$ and $y_2 = -x+\sqrt{x^2+2}$. That's how I arrived to the original inequality. One condition would be $-0.5<x<0.5$. However, I discarded cases when there are complex roots.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. It means that the solution set is empty. Actually, you should have considered $x\geq 1$, not $x>1$.

Comment: Ok, what about the other case?

Comment: It will make sense if complex numbers are included, but if they are not then the solution set will be empty

Comment: Empty again, since a square root is always nonnegative.

Comment: @Arjang What does $<$ mean in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense either, since RHS is negative, and square root is less than negative number.

Comment: @Arjang inequalities are not defined for complex numbers, only for reals.

Comment: @Kaster Yes, it makes sense. This just means that there are no solutions.

Comment: @julien same argument as "I have zero apples" and "I don't have any apples".

Comment: @Kaster When the question is to solve an inequality, the answer is the solution set. In this case, it is $\emptyset$. And the answer is not: this does not make sense.

Comment: @julien : as it stands nothing but then one can rewrite the above as $\sqrt{|z|^2 + 2}|<|z|-1$  then it should reduce to the original when z has no imaginary parts.

Comment: @julien did I say anything about solution set? Read again my post, by carefully this time. I said "inequality when square root less than a negative number doesn't make sense".

Comment: @Arjang Solution set empty again, exactly the same proof.

Comment: @Kaster I have read and commented carefully. Have you read my last comment carefully? One does not say $\sqrt{x}<-2$ does not make sense. One rather says it has no solution.

Comment: @julien oh really? Said who?

Comment: @julien : Awesome! then extending to C served no purpose. when $x^2=-1$ had nol solution, they added $\mathbb C$, whats the next extension for this question?

Comment: @Kaster : it just sounds better, one can say $x^2=-1$ makes no snese in $\mathbb R$ or that it has no solution in $\mathbb R$, pick wihcever that sounds better.

Comment: @Arjang What do you mean? Awesome...etc... This has nothing to do with the reason why $\mathbb{C}$ was introduced. I you replace $x$ by $|z|$, then there are no $z$ solution either. That's all I've said.

Comment: A formula (or sequence of symbols) is said to *make sense* if it is a statement. Assuming $x$ is quantified over $\Bbb R$, saying $x^2<0$ is a statement, a false one for that matter. It makes sense to say it. Something which wouldn't make sense is $x=\setminus <3^2$ as it isn't a statement.

Comment: @Kaster Said me and Git Gud, for example. To add on Gid Gud's comment. For the inequality $\sqrt{x}<-2$ to "make sense" in $\mathbb{R}$, you need to restrict to $x\geq 0$. Otherwise, it does not indeed make sense since the square root of a negative number is not defined. So $\sqrt{x}<-2$ is a statement that makes sense for $x\geq 0$. And it is false.

Comment: @arkadiy I forgot to mention: you should keep the old question too. Type the new question after mentioning you're editing or something, so that the old answers don't become senseless.

Comment: @arkadiy Just do make sure: are you wanting both roots to be greater than $1$ in absolute value?

Comment: Yes, I corrected.

Comment: @arkadiy I don't think you're meant to consider $x,y\in \Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$. If, for instance, $x=1+i$, $\sqrt{x^2+2}$ wouldn't be well defined because you'd be squarerooting a non-real complex number.

Comment: @ Git Gud Thank you! Does this mean that most likely I would not be able to find answer if $x,y\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @arkadiy It depends on what one understands by "most likely". No problem.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we had a real number $x$ that was a solution to the inequality.

If it *were* the case that $x\geq 1$, then  we would have that $x^2+2<x^2-2x+1$, and hence $x<-0.5$; this is a contradiction, so our assumption that $x\geq 1$ must have been false. Therefore, if there are any solutions to the inequality, they will have to be strictly less than 1.

However, if  $x<1$, then $x-1<0$; but for any real number $x$, we have that $x^2+2\geq 0$ and so $\sqrt{x^2+2}>0$; therefore, we cannot have $\sqrt{x^2+2}<x-1$, which again is a contradiction, because we assumed that $x$ did satsify the inequality.

Therefore, there cannot be any real numbers $x$ that satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x\in \Bbb R$, if $x<-1$, then $x-1<0$. Therefore you'll get $0\leq \sqrt{x^2+2}<x-1<0$, because a square root is always non-negative. This imples $0<0$, which can't happen. If $x\ge 1$, as the OP pointed out, $\sqrt{x^2+2}<x-1 \iff x^2+2<x^2-2x+1\iff 2x<-1\iff x<-0.5$, then $\sqrt{x^2+2}<x-1$ can't happen either.

Therefore then the set of real numbers that satisfies that inequality is $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in real solutions then firstly you must have $x^2 + 2 > 0$, so $x^2 > -2$ but $x^2 > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so you must have $x>0$.

Assuming $x\geq1$ and squaring both sides gives $x^2 +2 < (x-1)^2$ expanding gives $x^2 + 2 < x^2 - 2x + 1$ which can be written as $1 < -2x$ and clearly there are no solutions to this since $x\geq1$. So if a solution $x$ exists, we must have $0<x<1$ but no such solution can exist because when $0<x<1$, $\sqrt{x^2+2} > 0$ yet the other side of the inequality, $x-1<0$. So no such solution in $\mathbb{R}$ exists.